How to let mouse hover effect apply to two overlayed images?
I have two images in the same div, one over another. I want the mouse hover effect to apply to both images when I move mouse over the image, and the background image will display to have the zoom effect. But I found only the one on the top will react to the hover. Is there anyway to let both images change simultaneously?


<div class="overlay transparent" onmousemove="zoom(event)"
  style="background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/de/de/2bdede0647e3cdf75b44ea33723201d9.jpg)">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/de/de/2bdede0647e3cdf75b44ea33723201d9.jpg" />
  <img src="https://media.nomadicmatt.com/2023/tropicalislandsfeature.jpg" />
</div>

<style>
  div.transparent {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: zoom-in;
  }

  div.transparent img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  div.transparent img {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  div.overlay {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.overlay img:nth-child(1) {
    position: relative;
    object-fit: contain;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  div.overlay img:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
</style>

<script>
 function zoom(e) {
            var zoomer = e.currentTarget;
            e.offsetX ? offsetX = e.offsetX : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
            e.offsetY ? offsetY = e.offsetY : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
            x = offsetX / zoomer.offsetWidth * 100
            y = offsetY / zoomer.offsetHeight * 100
            zoomer.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
        }
</script>




You can use the :has pseudo-class.

Lean more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
Can I use : https://caniuse.com/css-has

Edit : For this case you can use only :hover pseudo-class


<div class="overlay transparent" style="background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/de/de/2bdede0647e3cdf75b44ea33723201d9.jpg)">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/de/de/2bdede0647e3cdf75b44ea33723201d9.jpg" />
  <img src="https://media.nomadicmatt.com/2023/tropicalislandsfeature.jpg" />
</div>

<style>
  div.transparent {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  /*  div.transparent:has(img:hover) img{*/
  div.transparent:hover img{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  div.transparent img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  
  div.overlay {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  div.overlay img:nth-child(1) {
    position: relative;
    object-fit: contain;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  div.overlay img:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
</style>




Hi, thanks for your answer! I should have post my complete function. I actually want to hide the two image and then display the background image, using :has make the background image disappear too. I have updated my code to show what I exactly want to achieve.

@SamTest no problem, code updated

Hover effects occur when you hover on an element and I can see that you put the :hover pseudo class on the <img /> element. Since you stacked one img element against the other, your mouse recognises the element on the top (with a greater z-index) once you hover on it leaving the one behind unaffected. If you want to achieve a result where both the images to get affected by the hover effect in this case, consider adding the :hover pseudo to the parent div and then effecting the change on hover on the images.


 

 <div class="overlay transparent">
   <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/de/de/2bdede0647e3cdf75b44ea33723201d9.jpg" />
          <img src="https://media.nomadicmatt.com/2023/tropicalislandsfeature.jpg" />
 </div>
    
        <style>
          div.transparent {
            height: 150px;
            width: 250px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color:red;
          }
    
          div.transparent:hover{
    img {
            opacity: 0;
          }
    } 
    
          div.transparent img {
            transition: opacity 0.5s;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
          }
    
          div.overlay {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
          }
    
          div.overlay img:nth-child(1) {
            position: relative;
            object-fit: contain;
            z-index: 1;
          }
    
          div.overlay img:nth-child(2) {
            position: absolute;
            object-fit: contain;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
          }
        </style>
    
    




Hi, thanks for your answer! I should have post my complete function. I actually want to hide the two image and then display the background image, setting the div transparent will make the background image disappear too. I have updated my code.

well yeah, u don't need to make the div transparent if you want the background image to be displayed as it is still part of the div. but you can add to the div the :hover pseudo class and target the elements inside of it that you want to make a style change to.

Thanks! I think @SioGabx's is a more elegant approach :)
